# view the selected row detail in new page using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hi i want to display the selected row values details in next page,i am displayin only name and city in first page and remaining fields will view after clicking button.
 My html page

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="detailCtrlr.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Age</td>
<td>details</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in names">
<td>{{x.Name}}</td>
<td>{{x.City}}</td>
<td><a href="#/viewdetail" type="submit"  name="viewdetails" ng-click="detail()">view</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

my controller is

```
   var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("details.json").then(function(response) {
            $scope.names = response.data.records;
        });
$scope.detail=function(){
        //details code here
    }
    });
```

now i am getting all records in this page and displayed fine, now i want to see the other details of selected row in details page.

Comment: Do you use routing concept of AngularJS then it's possible to pass parameters from one page to another.

Comment: @Ajinkya i use routing concepts

Comment: Can you share controller.

Comment: @Ajinkya Can you show a link to some documentation showing what you mean? Thanks.

Comment: Sure - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams. Provides you for passing parameters from one route to another.

Comment: @Ajinkya my question is not passing parameters, I want to show the details of selected person in next page,for that i think we have to write some code in the controller in which i have given in detail(){ }

Comment: Can you share your routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i got solution for my question, My controller is

```
app.controller('homeController', function($scope, $http, $location,
         $rootScope, $filter, $window) {
    $http.get("app/components/shared/json/Patients.json").success(
            function(response) {
                $scope.emp = response.Employees

                    $scope.select = function(list) {
                    debugger;
                    //$rootScope.selected = list;
                    $scope.selected = list;
                    localStorage.setItem("NamesDetails", JSON
                            .stringify($scope.selected));
                    $location.path('/homeView')
                    console.log(list)
                }
                $scope.cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("NamesDetails"));
                console.log($scope.cart)

            })
})
```

and in Html

```
<td> <a ng-click="select(list)">view</a></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use local Storage to view all the data of selected row.
please find below code:

if you are getting unique id of each record then try this:

your html will : `<a href="#/viewdetail" type="submit"  name="viewdetails" ng-click="detail(x.id)">view</a>`

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http,$location,filter) {
        $http.get("details.json").then(function(response) {
            $scope.names = response.data.records;
        });

$scope.detail=function(SelectedRecordeid){

        var NameObj = $filter('filter')($scope.names, { id: SelectedRecordeid })[0];

        localStorage.setItem("NamesDetails",JSON.stringify(NameObj));

        $location.path('/viewdetail');
    }
    });
```

if you are not getting unique id of each record then try this by using name:
your html will : `<a href="#/viewdetail" type="submit"  name="viewdetails" ng-click="detail(x.Name)">view</a>`

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http,$location,filter) {
        $http.get("details.json").then(function(response) {
            $scope.names = response.data.records;
        });

$scope.detail=function(SelectedName){

        var NameObj = $filter('filter')($scope.names, { Name: SelectedName })[0];

        localStorage.setItem("NamesDetails",JSON.stringify(NameObj));

        $location.path('/viewdetail');
    }
    });
```

Now in your "viewdetail" page's Controller user below to ready data from local storage.

```
var getAlldata = IsBlank(localStorage.NamesDetails) ? [] : JSON.parse(localStorage.NamesDetails);
```

you will get all the data in "getAlldata" variable.

===================

Also you can get data in another page using following method.
in this case you have to call two separate service call.
rewrite below function

```
$scope.detail=function(SelectedRecordeid){
                         window.location.hash = '#/viewdetail?id=' + SelectedRecordeid;
        }
```

now in you second page use below code:

```
    function GetQueryString(key) {
    'use strict';
    var res,
        arrQueryStrings = window.location.hash.split("?"),
        queryStringCollection;

    if (arrQueryStrings[1] === undefined || arrQueryStrings[1] === null) {
        return null;
    }
    queryStringCollection = arrQueryStrings[1].split("&");
    $.each(queryStringCollection, function (index, value) {
        var queryStringName = value.split("=")[0];
        if (queryStringName === key) {
            res = value.split("=")[1];
        }
    });

    return res;
}

$scope.SelectedRecordeid = IsBlank(GetQueryString("id")) ? 0 : GetQueryString("id");
```

Now you have id of selected row in  $scope.SelectedRecordeid, so you can call service using this id and get the full details in second page.

Comment: yes, if you don't want use local storage then in the first page you don't need to load all the data. just load data which you required for first page along with unique Id of each record and the pass that id to another page and from that page load data based on id.  in this case you have two separate service call.

Comment: this is what i need but i am stuck with this can u give the solution for that.

Comment: that is very simple just put this code : window.location.hash = '#/viewdetail?id=' + SelectedRecordeid; in function $scope.detail and then in second page just read like : $scope.SelectedRecordeid = IsBlank(GetQueryString("id")) ? 0 : GetQueryString("id");

Comment: code for function GetQuerystring is function GetQueryString(key) {
    'use strict';
    var res,
        arrQueryStrings = window.location.hash.split("?"),
        queryStringCollection;

    if (arrQueryStrings[1] === undefined || arrQueryStrings[1] === null) {
        return null;
    }
    queryStringCollection = arrQueryStrings[1].split("&");
    $.each(queryStringCollection, function (index, value) {
        var queryStringName = value.split("=")[0];
        if (queryStringName === key) {
            res = value.split("=")[1];
        }
    });

    return res;
}

Comment: can you reply ur answer in textbox so i can upvote ur answer and can approve your answer

Comment: ya sure. i have added full details in my answer. please check it.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am little late to answer this but for those who are still facing this issue, here is my code which worked after banging my head for 3 days looking for the solution.

I am using ng-resource for showing details. I have a factory called "listfactory".

//listFactory.js

angular.module("main")
.factory('listFactory', function($resource){

```
        var url = 'data.json'
        return $resource(url, {}, {
            query:{ 
                method: "GET",
                params: {},
                isArray: true,
                cache: true,
                //transformResponse
                //interceptor
            },
            get: {
                method: "GET",
                params: {},
                isArray: true,
                cache: true,
           }
    })
```

});

//Controller "detailscontroller.js

.controller("detailsController", function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $route, listFactory){

```
            $scope.employee = {};
            $scope.employee = listFactory.get({id: $routeParams.id });
            $scope.employee.$promise.then(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                //$scope.employee = data[$routeParams.id];
                angular.forEach( data,function(employee){
            console.log(employee);
            if( employee.email == $routeParams.id ){
                $scope.employee = employee;
            }

             });
            
    });
```

});

Basically I am iterating over the loop to check if routeparams matches with the employee's email.
Hope this helps :)